# C# WinForms Charts configuration

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to plot a file's byte count over a C# WinForms bar graph. As such, the X-axis will have values 0-255 (if greater than zero) and the Y-axis varies upon the length of the file and the byte distribution. The code is as follows:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < byteDistribution.Count; i++)
        {
            if (byteDistribution[i] > 0)
            {
                Series series = new Series(i.ToString());

                series.Points.AddXY(i, byteDistribution[i]);
                // PointWidth has no affect?
                series.SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "1");
                this.crtBytes.Series.Add(series);
            }
```

[image: Resultant chart]

**Questions:**

1. This works well but the way the chart is shown is not to my liking.
   I would like each bar to fill in as much space as possible (ie. no
   margin / border). From what I've read elsewhere it was suggested to
   use PointWidth or PixelPointWidth but none of these approaches is
   working.
2. Is there a way to remove the inner black grid lines from
   showing? Ideally, I would like the bottom X-axis numbering to remain just the same, but remove the grid lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing the gaps:

```
series["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

For removing the gridlines:

```
chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid = new FChart.Grid {Enabled = false};
chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid = new FChart.Grid { Enabled = false };
```

UPDATE:

I think your problem is that you create a new series for each data point. So you also get the "color effect". Just create ONE series, add it to the chart area and add all data points to this series.

```
Series series = new Series();
this.crtBytes.Series.Add(series);
series.SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "1");

for (int i = 0; i < byteDistribution.Count; i++)
{
    if (byteDistribution[i] > 0)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(i, byteDistribution[i]);
        // PointWidth has no affect?
    }
}
```

Comment: The _MajorGrid_ does work! however the PointWidth still has no effect. I had used the _SetCustomProperty_ function which should have the same effect, however it is not working...

Comment: Add all the points to the same series does work, however I was rather fond of that 'color effect' :p Is there a way to retain it maybe?

Comment: Yep. Adding colors to Points is just a trivial matter. Thanks for your help. I shall accept your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. `PointWidth` property is a relative amount, try something like `series["PointWidth"] = 1.25`.
2. The black lines are called MajorGrid, use `chartArea.MajorGrid.Enabled = False`.

Comment: The _MajorGrid_ does work! however the PointWidth still has no effect. I had used the _SetCustomProperty_ function which should have the same effect, however it is not working...