# how to pass selected row to draw a graph in another form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, graph, draw

I want to  below steps in using Visual studio in C#:

I read the .csv file but I can't pass the selected 2 rows to draw the graph in form.cs.please give help for me.if you can give any code example,it's a great advance for me.thank you.I coded it below as follows,I want to pass that selected column value and draw a graph in another form by using visual studio in C#.
my .csv file look like as follows:
Date,Cycle,Schedule,Step,AvT1,St1,TargetE1,AvE1,AvI1
7/2/2017,11:19,0,1,25.978,State1,0,-0.2248319,0.0066
7/2/2017 ,11:19,0,1,25.978,State1,0,-0.2264814,0.0088
7/2/2017,11:19,0,2,25.978,State1,0,-0.2322548,0.0088
7/2/2017 ,11:19,0,2,,25.978,State1,0,-0.2583174,0.0088

(consider AvE1 as x axis and AvI1 as y axis)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace GraphCsvInput
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView my_gridview = new DataGridView();
        DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();

        //private Form2 frm2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(750,500);
            my_gridview.Size = new Size(600,400);
            my_gridview.Location=new Point(5,5);

            string[] raw_txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C://Users//SampleGraphFile_CSV.csv");
            string []data_col = null;
            int x = 0;
            foreach(string text_line in raw_txt)
            {

                data_col = text_line.Split(',');
                if(x==0)
                {for(int i=0;i<=data_col.Count()-1;i++)
                {
                    my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                }

                    x++;
                }
                else
                {

                    my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);

                }
              // MessageBox.Show(data_col[6]);
            }
            my_gridview.DataSource = my_datatable;
            this.Controls.Add(my_gridview);


        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to achieve? How your csv looks like and what you want to make out of it?

Comment: Thank you very much  for response my question .I am newer to C# language.I have problem to calling between class and forms.I want do below steps;1. Read the .csv file.
2. Store interested parameters in a Class model.
3. Use Graph generation into a Manager class and introduce methods to draw  graph.
4. Above methods should read the Class object and draw the Graph.I want to read the .csv file and get selected row and pass that data to draw a graph according to X and y axis.thank you for your cooperation for my question.

Comment: Basic point remains the same... How your csv looks like? You can update the question and paste sample rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Create a class to hold the values like...

```
public class GraphsData
{
    public double XAxis { get; set; }
    public double YAxis { get; set; }
}
```

Then call the following method which will produce the result pasted below.

```
public static void CreatGraph()
    {
        var raw_txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\Projects\\GraphData.csv");

        var v2 = from p in raw_txt.Skip(1)
                 select new GraphsData
                 {
                     XAxis = double.Parse((p.Split(','))[7]),
                     YAxis = double.Parse((p.Split(','))[8])
                 };


        foreach (var item in v2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.XAxis + " | " + item.YAxis);    
        }

    }
```

This will produce following output

```
-0.2248319 | 0.0066
-0.2264814 | 0.0088
-0.2322548 | 0.0088
-0.2583174 | 0.0088
```

**IMP**

*Your CSV is not correctly formed. In the last line, notice the 2 commas, which may produce wrong result.*

**UPDATE TO CREATE GRAPH**

```
 public void CreatGraph()
    {

        var raw_txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\GraphData.csv");
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("x_axis");
        dt.Columns.Add("y_axis");

        DataTable myData = raw_txt.Skip(1)
                  .Select(x =>
                  {
                      var row = dt.NewRow();
                      row.SetField<string>("x_axis", x.Split(',')[7]);
                      row.SetField<string>("y_axis", x.Split(',')[8]);
                      return row;
                  }).CopyToDataTable();

        chart1.Series.Add("test");
        chart1.Series["test"].XValueMember = "x_axis";
        chart1.Series["test"].YValueMembers = "y_axis";
        chart1.DataSource = myData;
        chart1.DataBind();
    }
```

Insert a graph control on form (name of my control is "chart1"). Then on click of a button call this function.

Comment: Thank you for your help very much sir.yes sir that last two column is my typing mistake.thank you sir.may I know how to pass that value to windows form application to draw a graph.if you can it it is big help me to understand this.I am a new learner to this language.I like to learn so can give any link to learning this keyword practices.

Comment: thank you for supporting me very much.can you tell how to pass this value to windows form application's form to draw a graph.I am new learner to this language.So can you explain.it's great help for me.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find the suitable way to draw graph in form.

Comment: Paste the code you used to plot the graph and I will be able to help further if required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892373/c-sharp-winforms-charts-configuration

Comment: I want to read .csv file above mentioned  and draw graph between AvE1 as x axis and AvI1 as y axis.I want to know how I pass value to x and y value to axis. This is windows form application.so I can't think how i pass to values to form chart to draw graph.if you can help me it is great help for me.thank you